# Can some one tell me whats wrong in this looping implementation of child elements in react Js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to loop through the child elements so that multiple of them will appear under Div tag.

```
import React from 'react';
import StatusActivity from './App.js';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class App extends React.Component{
render(){
        return (
<div > {
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){ 
            <h1 > asdf </h1> //looping here for h1 tag
        }
}</div >
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: you can work like this 
   render(){
        let heading = [
            {id:1,
                content:"heading 1"},
            {id:2,
                content:"heading 2"},
            {id:3,
                content:"heading 3"},
            {id:4,
                content:"heading 4" }
        ];
           let headings = heading.map((value, index)=>{
                return(<h1 key={index}>{value.content}</h1>)
           })
        return(
            <div>{headings}</div>
        );
    }

Comment: Make an object and put your headings inside and then use map loop, it will draw correctly as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. move your for loop inside render and outside return
> 2. You can push jsx elements into an array and render them inside div like below
> 3. Also never forget to add unique key to h1 element inside loop

Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import StatusActivity from './App.js';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
     const items = [];
     for(var i=0;i<4;i++){ 
        items.push(<h1key={`Key_${i}`}> asdf </h1>)
     }
     return (
        <div >{items}</div>
     );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: This doesn't fix issue...It says, Failed to compile

Comment: Line 10:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   8 |   return (
   9 | <div > {
> 10 |         for(i=0;i<4;i++){ 
     |         ^
  11 |             return <h1 > asdf </h1> //looping here for h1 tag
  12 |         }
  13 | }</div >

Comment: can you please paste above comment in an editor, it would show properly

Comment: I know this approach..but was expecting answer why the earlier one was failing...Any ways thanks...

Comment: items.push(<h1 key={i}> asdf </h1>)

Comment: @riazshah Thank you. My bad I missed that

Comment: @santosh as per my knowledge for loop won't work inside return. You have to put that outside return and render jsx elements. Please accept the answer if that resolves the issue